# Replace spaces with first character of the line on each line

Tags: regex, awk

I have data that looks like this:

```
1, 100 200 3030 400 50023
2, 30 444 44334 441 123332
3, 100 200 3030 400 50023
```

I need to turn it into this:

```
1, 100
1, 200
1, 3030
1, 400
1, 50023
2, 30
2, 444
2, 44334
2, 441
2, 123332
etc.
```

I was able to do it with a vim macro but the data is far too. I was hoping something like awk could do it. But I am not really familiar with it.

Any help would be apperciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat input
1, 100 200 3030 400 50023
2, 30 444 44334 441 123332
3, 100 200 3030 400 50023
$ awk '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s %s\n", $1, $i}' input
1, 100
1, 200
1, 3030
1, 400
1, 50023
2, 30
2, 444
2, 44334
2, 441
2, 123332
3, 100
3, 200
3, 3030
3, 400
3, 50023
```

Comment: Please add explanation as well

Comment: starting a loop from staring from  2 to NF ( Internal awk variable containing the total number of field) with an increment of 1. File is space separated i.e $1 (first column) will have value as ( '1,' , '2,' ) and column values starting from 2 will be cycled

Comment: I wouldn't worry about `printf`, simply `print $1,$i` will do using the default `OFS`.

Comment: I don't see how an explanation would be any clearer than the code.  Iterate over the fields starting at field 2, printing each with field 1 as a prefix.  Further explanation belongs in a awk tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

```
 awk -F',' '{split($2,a," "); for (i in a)  print $1, "," , a[i]}'
```

explanation:

```
 awk -F',' -- Set field seprator as , 
'{split($2,a," "); -- Split column 2 using " "(space) as delimiter and populate array a 
for (i in a)  print $1, "," , a[i]} -- Loop to access all element of array'
```

Demo :

```
 renegade@Renegade:~$ cat test.txt 
1, 100 200 3030 400 50023
2, 30 444 44334 441 123332
3, 100 200 3030 400 50023
renegade@Renegade:~$ awk -F',' '{split($2,a," "); for (i in a)  print $1, "," , a[i]}'  test.txt 
1 , 100
1 , 200
1 , 3030
1 , 400
1 , 50023
2 , 30
2 , 444
2 , 44334
2 , 441
2 , 123332
3 , 100
3 , 200
3 , 3030
3 , 400
3 , 50023
renegade@Renegade:~$
```

Comment: You can use string-concatenation to get rid of the space, `print $1",", a[i]`. It's actually a nice answer, though there are more straight forward ways, this certainly isn't bad.